# Compiling C code with g++: Invalid conversion

Tags: c++, c, c99, c11

I'm compiling c code with g++ and running in some problems.
after fixing designated initializers I'm left with this error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to '__u8*'
```

This is my code:

```
static inline void put_unaligned_le16(__u16 val, __u16 *cp)
    {
        __u8    *p = (void *)cp;

        *p++ = (__u8) val;
        *p++ = (__u8) (val >> 8);
    }
```

Any help fixing this is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: The error is pretty clear: you are trying to initialize a `__u8*` with a `void*`, which is legal in C (implicit conversion) but _not in C++_ (whose type system is "safer"). Either compile with GCC or explicitly cast `cp` to `__u8*` (but beware of strict aliasing issues...)

Comment: In c++ void pointer must be explicitly typcasted.

Answer (score 4):

Don't try to compile C code using a C++ compiler. Ever. They are very distinct, different languages.

---

(If you do nevertheless for some strange masochistic reason, then you have to cast `void *` to `__u8 *`, because in C++, implicit conversion from `void *` does not happen. Too bad.)

Comment: Thanks! However I want to modify this gadgetfs example (www.linux-usb.org/gadget/usb.c) and therefor need to use  c++ code .

Comment: @tzippy I don't understand why you **have to.** That's a C file. Compile it using a C compiler.

Comment: I want to use std::vector so I need the g++ compiler. What's bad about that?

Comment: @tzippy You don't want to use `std::vector` **inside usb.c,** do you?

Comment: Ok, could you please explain a little why that's a bad idea instead of asking rhetorical questions that are not very helpful to me?

Comment: @tzippy It was not rhetorical. I asked whether or not you want to use `std::vector` from within a C file. If so, then rename it to `.cpp` and treat the code as C++. If not, then use separate compilers for C and C++ source files. And I've already given the reasoning: C and C++ are different languages and therefore are not interchangeable.

Comment: Okay, I actually did change the extension to .cpp. I always thought it was "downwards compatible"?

Comment: @tzippy Time to change that thought - unfortunately, it isn't.

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing that out. Actually I do run in some trouble at the moment with the open() of the file descriptor.